# typedef-name as base class: illegal but widely tolerated

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef

The first paragraph of [class.derived] says of base class specifiers,

> If the name found is not a class-name, the program is ill-formed.

However, a [simple](http://ideone.com/Yamoo) test shows that Comeau and `g++ -ansi -pedantic` both accept a typedef-name as a base. A simple `grep -r '[^:]: mpl'` over the Boost headers shows that popular library often relies on such behavior.

Has any compiler ever actually rejected a `typedef` of a class in a base specifier? GCC even checks that the base class type is not `const`, which refines the nonstandard functionality.

Is there a workaround? The only thing I can think of is to replace the typedef with a C++11 alias template. A templated alias-declaration declares a template-name which may then become a class-name… I think. This may require a dummy parameter to the alias-declaration.

Perhaps the Standard should be adjusted to match the unanimous behavior of the compilers. Is there a DR?

Comment: For the record: [DR 484 Can a base-specifier name a cv-qualified class type?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#484) points at C++11 §9.1/5: "If a typedef-name that names a cv-qualified class type is used where a class-name is required, the cv-qualifiers are ignored." So, this is a GCC bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is in accordance with the standard. Specifically, §9.1/5: "A *typedef-name* (7.1.3) that names a class is a *class-name*, [...]".

Comment: Hah! I only looked up the constructive definition of *class-name*. Thanks! (Grr, must wait one minute.)

Comment: Now, that raises the question of what is supposed to happen with a `const`-qualified base class type… time for more digging…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the standard must be viewed holistically -- which means only those who've memorized the whole blasted thing can ever be *entirely* sure of anything (and of course *nobody's* memorized it all)!

Comment: @Jerry: Cmon, we both know Johannes…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: as good as Johannes is (and he definitely *is* good) I'm pretty sure he doesn't know it quite as well as Andrew Koenig (former editor) or Pete Becker (current editor). It's so big, most of the authors don't remember all the parts they personally wrote! I sent in some minor edits once (but a *lot* less than most committee members have written) and I don't even remember all the parts I wrote...

Comment: @Jerry: I kid, I kid. But, I wouldn't underestimate his ability to integrate. He's only been at it a couple years…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Like I said, he definitely *is* good. I've talked either in person or on Usenet with a substantial percentage of the committee, and Johannes is right in the same league with the best of them. Andrew has a bit of an unfair advantage though: he's as brilliant as a Johannes, *and* he's been involved for decades...

Comment: As for me compared to Andrew, I'm definitely not in his league. I'm looking up to him with awe and fear.

Comment: @Johannes: Awe is justified -- but you honestly are in his league, or at least can be when you have similar experience. Fear, at least from what I've seen, is not really justified -- at least IME, Andrew seems to be a really *nice* person.